# Storing updateable strings in firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, settings, preferences, browser-extension

I've been searching and reading how firefox addons manages preferences, but all the samples I found involves GUI windows and other complex things I don't need.

What I need is, I have a list of some regex patterns, which needs to be updated often without user interaction whenever it's needed.

So I want to have the initial regex stored in the firefox addon like preferences but without any gui to edit them, and then be able to edit those hardcoded preferences.

**Can someone show me an example on how to do this?**

I don't want a full example, just how should I store these preferences and then edit them programmatically, without involving gui windows like all the .xul files I found does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");

// Reading the preference
var regexp = /foobar/;   // default value
try
{
  regexp = new RegExp(Services.prefs.getCharPref("extensions.myExtension.regexp"));
}
catch (e)
{
  // Errors are expected, the preference might not exist yet
}

// Setting the preference
Services.prefs.setCharPref("extensions.myExtension.regexp", regexp.source);
```

You will be able to see this preference under `about:config`. [More code examples](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences)